# How does a certificate verify the identity of the owner of the web site?

Tags: ssl, certificate

I don't understand what value does an SSL certificate have to assure the users the website belongs to the entity written in the certificate.
Anyone can buy a domain and fill the certificate the way he wants, the Certificate Authority doesn't check the id of the owner of the domain and compare it to what he fills in the certificate.
And then the certificate will show false information to users visiting the site.

Comment: [maybe this is a reponse](https://www.howtogeek.com/119723/htg-explains-how-browsers-verify-website-identities-and-protect-against-imposters/#:~:text=An%20EV%20certificate%20indicates%20that%20a%20certificate%20authority%20has%20verified,run%20by%20a%20specific%20organization.&text=This%20involves%20checking%20government%20records,certificate%20works%20for%20the%20organization.)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, the question now is why the browser doesn't warn you when you go to a website with a certificate that is not identity verified and post information or try to login there. But warns you so badly if a certificate is expired.

Comment: Also they warn users of a self signed certificate when those kind of certificates are exactly the same, they only secure the connection.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand what value does an SSL certificate have to assure the users the website is valid.

It does not have such a value. A certificate does not make any statements about a website being "valid" (whatever this is in the first place) or "secure" or similar statements about the content or the owner of a website. A certificate only ensures that the website reached is the domain shown in the URL. This way it protects against man in the middle attacks on the communication.

> ...  the Certificate Authority doesn't check the id of the owner of the domain and compare it to what he fills in the certificate

For domain validation (DV) certificates no domain owner is even shown in the certificate, but only the domain name. And it is checked by the CA that the one asking for the certificate has actually control over the domain. Extended validation (EV) certificates contain owner information - which are also verified by the CA.

Comment: So what's its point? How will users know what is the domain the company they try to reach use?

Comment: @RonenFestinger: *"How will users know what is the domain the company they try to reach use?"* - definitely not by trying various domain names, looking at the certificate and checking if the information there shows that they've reached the correct site. Finding the right domain is done by using a search engine, looking at ads which include the domain name, looking at business directories etc - similar to how one would look for a phone number.

Comment: And why not just use a trusted search engine for validating the domain is legit, I mean clicking in a search engine results, instead of using EV certificate?

Comment: @RonenFestinger: Certificates are used to protect against man in the middle attacks. The man in the middle is between the client and the server and might not be between search engine and server. Thus, the search engine might see the correct certificate while the client gets the attackers certificate. This means that one cannot rely on the search engine here.